# Find the residues of $F(z) = \frac{\pi \sec \pi z}{z^3}$ at $z = n+ \frac{1}{2}$, $n = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the residues of $F(z) = \frac{\pi \sec \pi z}{z^3}$ at $z = n+ \frac{1}{2}$, $n = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots$

This is a practice problem in Schaum's. The solution says:

$$\lim_{z \to n + 1/2} \left[ z - \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right) \right] \frac{\pi}{z^3 \cos \pi z} = \frac{\pi}{z^3 \cos \pi z} = \frac{\pi}{\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)^3} \lim_{z \to n+\frac{1}{2}} \frac{z - \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)}{\cos \pi z} = \frac{ - (-1)^n}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^3}.$$

What properties of residues are we using to get this solution? How is the above solution derived?

Comment: The zeros of $\cos$ are all simple, so the poles of $F$ except the pole at $0$ are all simple. In a simple pole $a$ of $F$, the residue is $$\lim_{z\to a} \left((z-a)\cdot F(z)\right).$$ I prefer to use that if $z_0$ is a simple zero of $g$, then the residue of $\frac{f}{g}$ in $z_0$ is $$\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to see what kind of singularities you have. For $z\to 0$:
$$
\frac{\sec (\pi z)}{z^3} = \frac{1}{\cos(\pi z)z^3} = \frac{1}{z^3 + O(z^5)} = z^{-3}\left(1+O\left(z^2\right)\right)
$$
So $0$ is a pole of order $3$ and the resiude of the function there is:
$$
res_0 F = \frac{1}{2!} \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(z^3F(z)\right)
$$
You can calculate the value explicitly if you feel like it.

All the other poles are the roots of $\cos$, to see the order of the poles (at this point I'm cheating since a priori we don't know they are poles), we first consider its Taylor expansion when $z\to \pi(n+1/2)$. If $n$ is even:
$$
\cos(z) = - \left(z-\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) + O\left(\left(z-\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^3\right) 
$$ 
If $n$ is odd just change the sign.

Let me call $\left(\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) - z\right) = w$. So, near those points :
$$
\frac{1}{\cos (w) z^3} = \frac{z^{-3}}{w + O\left(w^3\right)} = z^{-3}w^{-1}\frac{1}{1+O\left(w^2\right)} =  z^{-3}w^{-1}\left(1+O\left(w^2\right)\right) 
$$
So all these points are simple poles.

There's pretty simple way to calculate the residue of simple poles. If $z_0$ is a simple pole of a function $f$, then:
$$
res_{z_0}f= \lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0) f(z)
$$
Using the previous results yields your result. Typing it became quite messy with TeX, but I'm pretty sure you can follow from here. If you have any doubt don't hesitate to ask.